# Avro : Custom deserialiser for a field

Tags: java, deserialization, avro, avro-tools

I have an avro schema with below as one of the fields:

```
"name": "UUId", 
"type": {
  "name": "FixedBytesUUId", 
  "type": "fixed", 
  "size": 16
}
```

Now, when I deserialise a record with value "1234567891234567", it gets deserialised like this:

```
"UUId": [49, 50, 51, 52, 53, 54, 55, 56, 57, 49, 50, 51, 52, 53, 54, 55]
```

Is there any way I can specify the format/config during deserialisation? Below is my code to deserialise:

```
GenericRecord record = new GenericDatumReader<GenericRecord>(schema)
        .read(null, DecoderFactory.get()
        .jsonDecoder(schema, data));

System.out.println(record);
```

Comment: What kind of output do you want?

Comment: @Admit I want output like : `"UUId" : "1234567891234567"`

Comment: I think the type fixed is not your choice then. Is `int` acceptable?

Comment: Unfortunately we can't change the type. Can we write a custom serialiser/deserialiser to convert to and from byte array?